# Plexgear WiFi Adapter (RTL8811AU) Driver Installation Issue on Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem

I have bought a Plexgear network card from this [website](https://www.kjell.com//no/produkter/nettverk/tradlost-nettverk/tradlose-nettverkskort/plexgear-tradlost-usb-nettverkskort-600-mbs-p61346?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwwMqvBhCtARIsAIXsZpams0O8PCXJWew-sOdwqnRwkqui0VQowhxkhTebVS-DhHLXmN5PbhYaAt9XEALw_wcB)

downloaded and installed the [driver](https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629) from

on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu Desktop.

How can I check that my driver and network card are working toghter?

Comment: Do `lsusb -t` and find your network card.